# How to find most perfect matching of some part of a string with an object's string value from a list of objects in javascript?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have a list in frontend **storedList**. I need to check if some part of string **str1** perfectly matches with any value of **text** parameter in **storedList**.
I have tried using includes() and got output given below.

```
let storedList = [
    { id: 1, text: 'Higher Education' },
    { id: 2, text: 'Higher Education in Physics' },
    { id: 3, text: 'Higher Education in Chemistry' },
    { id: 4, text: 'Higher Education in Math' },
    { id: 5, text: 'Higher Education in Biology' },
    { id: 6, text: 'Higher Education in History' },
    { id: 7, text: 'Higher Education in Economics' },
];

let str1 = 'unnecessay texts Higher Education in Biology unnecessary texts';

for (let row of storedList) {
    console.log(str1.includes(row.text));

    // output
    // true
    // false
    // false
    // false
    // true
    // false
    // false
}
```

Now I have two problems.

1. As we can see there are two **true** results for "Higher Education" and "Higher Education in Biology". But I only want the last one as it is more accurate than the first one. How to do that?
2. My **storedList** might have upto 60,000 objects in the list. So for checking the string **str1** I need to loop for 60,000 times with my process! And what if I have to check the storedList for 1000 different strings. It's 60,000 * 1000 times!

Really need a better and efficient solution.

Comment: Consider [Levenshtein distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance) if you are trying to determine how similar two strings are to each other. [Here](https://gist.github.com/andrei-m/982927) is a javascript implementation. Or check out this [npm module](https://www.npmjs.com/package/fast-levenshtein).

Comment: A better solution would be create an index for the `storedList`, in the simplest form it would be a dictionary `word => array of text ids`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Array.reduce()` and take the object with the longer text, which is also included in `str1`:

```js
const storedList = [
  { id: 1, text: 'Higher Education' },
  { id: 2, text: 'Higher Education in Physics' },
  { id: 3, text: 'Higher Education in Chemistry' },
  { id: 4, text: 'Higher Education in Math' },
  { id: 5, text: 'Higher Education in Biology' },
  { id: 6, text: 'Higher Education in History' },
  { id: 7, text: 'Higher Education in Economics' },
];

const str1 = 'unnecessay texts Higher Education in Biology unnecessary texts';

const result = storedList.reduce((r, o) =>
  o.text.length > r.text.length && str1.includes(o.text) ? o : r
);

console.log(result);
```

Comment: thanks for this answer. It solves my first problem. Can you tell if it will freeze my browser to call this reduce() operation for 60,000 times for 1000 string?

Comment: I should have stated that this is a solution for the 1st problem. It might hang your browser if you try to search 1000 strings.